# Accumulation point for closure wrt two particular contracting affine maps on $(-1,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $B(x)=\frac{3x+1}{4}$ and $C(x)=\frac{3x-1}{4}$. Then $(-1,1)$ is a stable interval for both $B$ and $C$. Let $S\subseteq (-1,1)$ be nonempty and stable by both $B$ and $C$. Note that for any initial value $x_0$, the iterates $B^n(x_0)$ and $C^n(x_0)$ converge to $1$ and $-1$ respectively, so $1$ and $-1$ are accumulation points for $S$.

**My question:** Is $0$ an accumulation point for $S$ ?

**What I tried :** With the help of a computer, I found that if we put

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f(x)&=&CBBCBCBCCBBCCBCBBCBB \\
& & CCBBCBCCBBCBCCBBCCBB \\
& & CCBCBBCCBBCCBCBBBCCC \\
& & BBBCBBCCB(x) \\
r&=&\frac{15571040882549573754344675288597}{348449142892655818255415064238273319835661} \approx 4 \times 10^{-11}
\end{array}
$$

then $f$ has the property that $0<f(x)<x$ whenever $x\gt r$, because $x-f(x)=\bigg(1-\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^{69}\bigg)(x-r)$. In particular $S$ always contains an element in $(0,r]$. I see no clear pattern in the above long string of $C$'s and $B$'s though.

Comment: What is a stable interval? What does it mean for $S$ to be stable by both $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson A set $X$ is stable by a map $f$ when $f(X) \subseteq X$ : in other words, the image of an element in the set stays in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For any  $\varepsilon>0$, it is possible to map the interval $(-1,1)$
>   inside the interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ via some composition
>   of the maps $B$ and $C$.

*Proof:*
Every point in $(-1,1)$ is mapped to by either  $B$ or $C$ i.e. $B(-1,1)\cup C(-1,1)=(-1,1)$. Hence $BB(-1,1)\cup BC(-1,1)\cup CB(-1,1) \cup CC(-1,1)=(-1,1)$ and likewise for the length $n$ strings of $B$s and $C$s. Therefore for any $n$ there exists a string of $B$s and $C$s of length $n$ whose image contains $0$. By choosing sufficiently large $n$ we can force this image to be within an arbitrarily small interval.

*If $S$ is non-empty then there exists a string of $B$s and $C$s which maps any $x_0\in S$ to a point in $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. Therefore zero is an accumulation point of $S$.*

Comment: Brilliantly simple. In fact, for a string of length $n$, the image has length exactly $(\frac{3}{4})^n$. And this argument also shows that $S$ must be dense in all of $(-1,1)$. I'll wait to award the bounty, which will perhaps allow you to get a few more upvotes.

Comment: Each of $B$ and $C$ is $3/4$-Lipschitz, so they shrink intervals at least by $3/4$.